# Confusion Over The Definition of a Transposition Cipher

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations, cryptography

In our Discrete Mathematics class, the way the textbook introduces the transposition cipher is as follows:

> As
> a key we use a permutation $\sigma$ of the set $\{1, 2, \ldots , m\}$ for some positive integer $m$, that is, a one-to-one function from $\{1, 2, \ldots, m\}$ to itself. To encrypt a message we first split its letters into blocks of size $m$. We encrypt the block $p_1p_2\ldots p_m$ as $c_1c_2\ldots c_m = p_{\sigma(1)}p_{\sigma(2)}\ldots, p_{\sigma(m)}$. To decrypt a ciphertext block $c_1c_2, \dots c_m$, we transpose its letters using the permutation $\sigma^{−1}$, the inverse of $\sigma$.

And then an example is brought up, where a transposition cipher is done.

> Using the transposition cipher based on the permutation $\sigma$ of the set $\{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ with $\sigma(1) = 3$, $\sigma(2) = 1$, $\sigma(3) = 4$, and $\sigma(4) = 2$, encrypt the plaintext message PIRATE ATTACK...We first split the letters of the plaintext into blocks of four letters. We obtain PIRA TEAT TACK. To encrypt each block, *we send the first letter to the third position, the second letter to the first position, the third letter to the fourth position, and the fourth letter to the second position*. We obtain IAPR ETTA AKTC.

The confusion arises because given the notation $c_1c_2\ldots c_m = p_{\sigma(1)}p_{\sigma(2)}\ldots p_{\sigma(m)}$, wouldn't the ciphered text be in the form $p_3p_1p_4p_2$ (rather than the suggested $p_2p_4p_1p_3$)? I've looked online and it may be that the difference is caused because the permutation is an active permutation, not a passive one, but I still find this to not make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the most intuitive explanation of a transposition cipher is that we move the letter in position $k$ to position $\sigma(k).$ That is how the example is done.

But you're right, this contradicts the way the transposition for a permutation $\sigma$ was defined earlier. In order to be consistent with the example, the definition should have been

$$ c_1c_2\ldots c_m = p_{\sigma^{-1}(1)}p_{\sigma^{-1}(2)},\ldots,p_{\sigma^{-1}(m)}.$$

Answer (score 2):

You’re right; they did it the wrong way around.